# Java Authenticator on a per connection basis?

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, authenticator

I'm building an Eclipse plugin that talks to a REST interface which uses Basic Authentication. When the authentication fails I would like to popup my plugin's settings dialog and retry. Normally I could use the static `Authenticator.setDefault()` to setup an authenticator for all `HttpURLConnection`'s  for this, but since I am writing a plugin I don't want to overwrite Eclipse's default `Authenticator` (`org.eclipse.ui.internal.net.auth`);

I thought of setting my custom `Authenticator` before loading and putting Eclipse's default back afterwards, but I imagine this will cause all sorts of race issues with multithreading so I quickly lost that notion.

Google searches yield all sorts of results basically telling me it's not possible:

> The Java URLConnection API should have a setAuthenticator(Authenticator) method for making it easier to use this class in multi-threaded context where authentication is required.

[Source](http://blog.taragana.com/index.php/archive/java-tip-basic-authentication-with-httpurlconnection/)

> If applications contains few third party plugins and each plugin use its own Authenticator what we should do? Each invocation of "Authenticator.setDefault()"  method rewrite previously defined Authenticator...

[Source](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4941958)

Are there any different approaches that might help me overcome this issue?

Comment: +1 I have the same problem. Very annoying!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If it is not possible with HttpURLConnection I would suggest using the [httpclient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) library from Apache.

A quick example:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.getState().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials("test","test"));
GetMethod getMethod = new GetMethod("http://www.example.com/mylogin");
client.executeMethod(getMethod);
System.out.println(getMethod.getResponseBodyAsString());
```

Comment: yeah The apache commoms http client is what i had settled on using if this issue with the JRE default HttpURLConnection is onovercomeable. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: In the end opting for a 3rd party Http class was the only viable solution, so i'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be to perform the basic authentication yourself on the connection.

```
    final byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.encodeData((username + ':' + new String(password)).getBytes("iso-8859-1"));
    final String encoded = new String(encodedBytes, "iso-8859-1");

    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
```

This would also have the advantage of not requiring an unauthenticated request to receive a 401 before providing the credential on a subsequent request. Similar behavior can be leveraged in the apache http-client by requesting preemptive authentication.

Comment: Thanks a LOT! You saved my day. Authenticator.setDefault is a complete CRIME...